# xslt space delimited attribute and match

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a XML like below:

```
<root>
    <tag1 type="TEST" id="111" name="name1" contents="test1 test2 test3">
        <othertags></othertags>
    </tag1>
    <tag1 type="TEST" id="222" name="name2" contents="test6 test8 test10">
        <othertags></othertags>
    </tag1>

    <tag2 id="test1" name="aaa" version="1"></tag2>
    <tag2 id="test2" name="bbb" version="2"></tag2>
    <tag2 id="test3" name="ccc" version="3"></tag2>
    <tag2 id="test6" name="fff" version="6"></tag2>
    <tag2 id="test8" name="hhh" version="8"></tag2>
    <tag2 id="test10" name="jjj" version="10"></tag2>

    <othertags></othertags>
</root>
```

The contents attribute in node `<tag1 type="TEST">` is separated by white space. I would like to use it and get the name and version from `<tag2>` node for corresponding contents. So the expected output would be something like for each content:

```
<Group>
<TagName>name1</TagName>
<ContentID>test1</ContentID>
<ContentName>aaa</ContentName>
<Version>1</Version>
</Group>
```

I have managed to process the first two required nodes, but left stuck with the rest three nodes. Appreciate for any help!
My xslt is (without header declaration):

```
 <xsl:template match="tag1[@type='TEST']" name="split">
  <xsl:param name="sContents" select="@contents"/>
  <xsl:param name="sName" select="@name"/>
  <xsl:param name="sContentID" select="'ContentID'"/>
  <xsl:param name="sTName" select="'TagName'"/>

    <xsl:if test="string-length($sContents) > 0">
     <xsl:variable name="sNextItem" select=
      "substring-before(concat($sContents, ' '), ' ')"/>

      <xsl:element name="Group">
      <xsl:element name="{$sTName}">
    <xsl:value-of select="$sName"/>
    </xsl:element>

      <xsl:element name="{$sContentID}">
    <xsl:value-of select="$sNextItem"/>
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>

  <xsl:call-template name="split">
    <xsl:with-param name="sContents" select=
                   "substring-after($sContents, ' ')"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="sName" select="$sName"/>
    <!--xsl:with-param name="sTName" select="$sTName"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="sContentName" select="$sContentName"/-->
   </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a key to look up the `tag2` values based on the `id` attribute

```
<xsl:key name="tag2" match="tag2" use="@id" />
```

To get the `name` attribute, for example, you would just do this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('tag2',$sNextItem)/@name"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:key name="tag2" match="tag2" use="@id" />

 <xsl:template match="tag1[@type='TEST']" name="split">
  <xsl:param name="sContents" select="@contents"/>
  <xsl:param name="sName" select="@name"/>
  <xsl:param name="sContentID" select="'ContentID'"/>
  <xsl:param name="sTName" select="'TagName'"/>
  <xsl:param name="sContentName" select="'ContentName'"/>

    <xsl:if test="string-length($sContents) > 0">
     <xsl:variable name="sNextItem" select="substring-before(concat($sContents, ' '), ' ')"/>

      <Group>
      <xsl:element name="{$sTName}">
       <xsl:value-of select="$sName"/>
      </xsl:element>

      <xsl:element name="{$sContentID}">
       <xsl:value-of select="$sNextItem"/>
      </xsl:element>

      <ContentName>
       <xsl:value-of select="key('tag2',$sNextItem)/@name"/>
      </ContentName>

      <Version>
       <xsl:value-of select="key('tag2',$sNextItem)/@version"/>
      </Version>
    </Group>

    <xsl:call-template name="split">
     <xsl:with-param name="sContents" select="substring-after($sContents, ' ')"/>
     <xsl:with-param name="sName" select="$sName"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```